# Is There A Browser Which Makes It Easy/Possible To Search From The Address Bar?

Tags: browser, search

For those familiar with the Google Chrome browser, I'm looking for the feature which basically treats the address bar as a search bar when not navigating to a site. I would find this handy since it's annoying to have to navigate to Google.com first (which is the only option on the stock browser) or using the search widget. Is there a browser for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dolphin Browser HD](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dolphin-browser%E2%84%A2-hd/mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) allows you to search google from the address bar, and it shows suggestions as you type.  It doesn't explicitly say that it has this feature but I use it all the time.  If you type something in the address bar that's not a web address and hit go it will automatically search, just like Chrome does.

Comment: I should also add that I've used the stock browser, Skyfire, the standar Dolphin Browser, Dolphin Browser HD, Opera Mini and Opera Mobile and Dolphin Browser HD is my favorite by far.

Comment: Yup, works just like Chrome. Another reason to switch to Dolphin Browser.

Answer (score 3):

What android version are you on? I've got eclair (on a motorola phone) and I can just type in the address bar to search. I thought it might be motoblur, but I tried an eclair emulator image and had the same functionality.

What happens when you hit the search button while the Browser is running?

Comment: +1 Now I realize that I wasn't searching but my search term was getting added to http! When I click the address and start typing my search term, I don't see the http until I scroll the address bar. I just have to manually delete the http text first. So searching this way, with the stock browser does "work." It turns out Dolphin HD deletes the http for you.

Answer (score 2):

[Opera Mini](http://www.appbrain.com/app/opera-mini-web-browser/com.opera.mini.android) places a Google search bar near the URL bar. This is not exactly what I was looking for but it's a potential alternative.