# Can I prevent the Android 2.2 browser from inserting "www" at the beginning of URLS?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, browser

I'm loving my Android phone (Incredible) but I cannot stand when the browser automatically inserts "www" at the beginning of any URL I'm trying to type. I am a web developer and work a lot with sub domains (not to mention blind usage of "www" is bad practice) and it gets frustrating.

Any ideas?

Comment: Then how would you know that you are on the world wide web?

Comment: I have never seen this behavior.  It must be Incredible-specific.

Comment: Is it entering it as you type or after you hit Go?  It is also helpful to mention what browser you are using when you see this behavior.  The Dolphin Browser HD doesn't do this to me however certain sites automatically redirect to the www. when no subdomain is submitted.  This is controlled at the site level by any url rewrite rules they have.

Comment: @Matt: He does say that he's using the Android browser. I've not seen this behavior either.

Comment: @Joel, I don't have this problem here either (Android 2.2 on HTC EVO).  Is it simply remembering a previous URL?

Comment: @Al: where does he say that?

Comment: "Can I prevent the Android 2.2 browser..." I definitely could've been clearer, sorry!
Thanks for the answers, guys!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be specific to the HTC Droid Incredible. When I first tried to search from the stock browser, I'd get an error page (I didn't notice the "http://www"). So I asked [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3190/15) which gave some options in the form of browsers which are ready for search queries. (It turns out you can search from the stock browser once you delete the "http://www")

You may want to use another browser. In the [Dolphin HD browser](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dolphin-browser%E2%84%A2-hd/mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) for example, the "www" isn't there so typing "android.stackexchange.com" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

1. Delete everything from the url textbox and enter the url, for example "android.stackexchange.com"
2. Remove the `www.` part and enter the rest of the url behind `http://`.

Both of these methods work on my Droid Incredible running stock 2.2 (rooted)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my phone here to try ... but can it be a specific keyboard which is selected ( and where words are automatically inserted ). F.i. using SWYPE and having word prediction on ?

Answer (score 0):

On the HTC Desire HD (2.2, standard browser), the behaviour when you tap in the address bar appears to be:

- If the URL currently in the address bar **already** starts with `www.` then everything **after** the `www.` is auto-selected, meaning that whatever you type will replace it, leaving the `www.` in place.
- If the URL currently in the address bar **doesn't** start with `www.` then the full URL (everything following `http://`) is selected, meaning that what you type will form the full URL.

I can't find a way of disabling this, and quite regularly end up trying to go to `www.www.google.com`.